# Eclipse & Java: How to designate folder as resources while not in src directory

Tags: java, eclipse, ant

I've got a folder tree like this:

```
Project Folder/
    src/
        *.java
    resources/
        *.png
```

The `build.xml` file includes the 2 whilst building, so all is well. (It copies the `resources` folder into the `src`, in a sense)

However, I've imported this structure into eclipse and the project crashes because it cannot locate its resources, as the resources folder is not in `src` as it likes. I've mitigated the issue by simply moving `resources` into `src` and modifying `build.xml`, but I would like to know how to get it working in eclipse as-is.

Here is an example of how resources are loaded:

```
public static ImageIcon createIcon(String fname,String desc) {
        URL imgURL = new Object().getClass().getResource("/resources/icons/"+fname);
        return new ImageIcon(imgURL,desc);
    }
```

Comment: `project crashes because it cannot locate its resources` please post the code you are using to access said resources. I have resources in a seperate directory and it works just fine for me. Click on the [edit] button above to include all relevant parts of your code so that we can help you debug.

Comment: @MattClark There you have it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to mark your resources folder as a source folder.  Select project, right-click -> Build path -> Use as source folder.

You may need to do a full rebuild after this.

Comment: Thanks! Any way to have it so that a `getResource` call still has to include the "/resources/xxxxxx.png" because this method seems to simply put it at "root" (i.e. `getResource("xxxx.png")` instead of `getResource("/resources/xxxx.png")`)

Comment: Nevermind. I added the project directory as a source folder, which seems somewhat hacky but perhaps not.